# How to hide the button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I write the some code in button event  I used the javascript and call the button event it is working fine here my problem is  i want hide the button 
i do this ways
visible=false this time the button event is not firing
enable =false
this time also button event is not firing
how can isolve this problemA

Comment: Please show us the code,

Comment: and reword your question, so it actually makes sense.

Comment: Are you still struggling with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using JavaScript

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Hide(id) {
            document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    </script>
</head>
...
<asp:Button ID="myButtonId" runat="server" OnClientClick="Hide('myButtonId')" Text="Hide Me" />
```

Or if you're trying to do it in code behind

YourPage.aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="myButtonId" runat="server" onclick="myButtonId_Click" Text="Hide Me" />
```

YourPage.aspx.cs

```
protected void myButtonId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    myButtonId.Visible = false;
}
```

Granted, this will result in a postback and your entire page will refresh. So if you don't want that to happen but still want to use the code behind approach, use an `UpdatePanel`.

Answer (score 0):

"Visible" is the property of asp:Button(Server) but not input:button(Client).